# Just get one data if duplicate (not DISTINCT)

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have the following result from a query in mysql (headers: depicao, arricao):

EDDH, EDDK
EDFH, EDDL
EDDS, EDDH
EDDK, EDDH

My problem is now, that I just want one of the rows, IF the data exist in the correlation "EDDH - EDDK" AND "EDDK - EDDH".

The query for this result is something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.depicao, p.arricao FROM xyz WHERE xxyyzz = 1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect for this specific dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order the columns in a consistent way with `GREATEST` and `LEAST`, then use `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT GREATEST(depicao, arricao) as col1, LEAST(depicao, arricao) AS col2
FROM xyz
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

If I do this with Greatest and Least the coordinates wont fit... Here's my standard query:
https://i.imgur.com/3JMdN06.png 
And the result:
https://i.imgur.com/UvBXoMM.png 
Thanks!

Comment: You need to replace all uses of `p.depicao` and `p.arricao` with the `GREATEST` and `LEAST` expressions to get all the columns consistent.

Comment: Thank you that works for me! :) Have a nice day, sir.

Answer (score 0):

I think `row_number()` does what you want:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by least(p.depicao, p.arricao), greatest(p.depicao, p.arricao) order by rand()) as seqnum
      from p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can add additional filtering conditions in the subquery, which you seem to have in your query but not your question.